# jQuery CSS on change works only on click?

Tags: javascript, jquery, onchange

My initial settings for 'buttons' that are created in function are like this.

```js
$(".save_w").css("color", "grey");
$(".save_w").css("pointer-events", "none");
```

HTML (simplified):

```html
<input class="input_w" type="text">

<i class="save_w far fa-save"></i>
```

Next, function is simple :

```js
$('body').on('change', '.input_w', function() {
  console.log("change");

  $(".save_w").css("pointer-events", "auto");
  $(".save_w").attr("color", "");
});
```

### What I want to achieve

After changing the value of  input with class `"input_w"`, css of `".save_w"` should be changed.

### What I get

When I change value of input, the `".save_w"` changes, but only after I click somewhere on the site (usually I click on another elements to trigger change). Why? There is no `onclick` method here.

Comment: The change is triggered on blur in this case, if you want it to change as the user is inputting stuff then you might want to use keypress https://api.jquery.com/keypress/ keyup or keydown

Comment: Consider using `keyup` versus `change` which is waiting for `blur` to determine if the value has changed. You can then check the length of the value and if it's larger than 1, change the CSS.

Comment: `keyup` and `keypress` are both insufficient because the input may be done through other means than key input. (For example, right-clicking and selecting "paste", or dragging text into the field, or selecting a value from the autocomplete dropdown.) `input` should be used instead.

Comment: Why are you applying event on body tag? isn't it would be input tag?

Comment: The input tag may be added afterwards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is another example that uses `input` and CSS to make the changes a bit easier.

```js
$(function() {
  $('body').on('input', '.input_w', function() {
    if ($(this).val().length > 1) {
      $(".save_w").addClass("active");
    } else {
      $(".save_w").removeClass("active");
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.save_w {
  color: gray;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.save_w.active {
  color: black;
  pointer-events: auto;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" integrity="sha384-wvfXpqpZZVQGK6TAh5PVlGOfQNHSoD2xbE+QkPxCAFlNEevoEH3Sl0sibVcOQVnN" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="input_w" type="text">

<i class="save_w far fa-save"></i>
```

Answer (score 1):

The `change` event fires only after the change is committed by leaving the form field:

> The change event is fired for `<input>`, `<select>`, and `<textarea>` elements when an alteration to the element's value is committed by the user. Unlike the `input` event, **the `change` event is not necessarily fired for each alteration to an element's value**.
>
> Depending on the kind of element being changed and the way the user interacts with the element, the `change` event fires at a different moment:
>
> [...]
>
> - **When the element loses focus** after its value was changed, but not commited (e.g., after editing the value of `<textarea>` or `<input type="text">`).

(Emphasis mine. - [Source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/change_event))

The `input` event may be more to your liking:

> The `input` event fires when the value of an `<input>`, `<select>`, or `<textarea>` element has been changed.
>
> [...]
>
> **Note**: The input event is fired every time the value of the element changes. This is unlike the `change` event, which only fires when the value is committed, such as by pressing the enter key, selecting a value from a list of options, and the like.

([Source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/input_event))

Answer (score 1):

Changing event `change` to `input` is all you needed.

```
$('body').on('input', '.input_w', function() {
  console.log("change");

  $(".save_w").css("pointer-events", "auto");
  $(".save_w").attr("color", "grey");
});
```